# search and display string from group of string php

Tags: php, string

i want to know how to search and display string from group of string like google display the word which we search...

the following example from google

search word is google books

result

Search and preview millions of books from libraries and publishers worldwide using **Google Book** Search. Discover a new favorite or unearth an old classic.

i would like to do this type of one...

thanks and advance

Comment: So, you want to search for text within a large string?

Comment: yes, i want this type of search.

Comment: do u know answer of this questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$searchString = "Google Book";

$originalString = "Search and preview millions of books from libraries and publishers worldwide using Google Book Search. Discover a new favorite or unearth an old classic.";

$outputString = preg_replace("/($searchString)/i",'<strong>${1}</strong>',$originalString);
```

This should do a case-insensitive search and replace of your search string so that it becomes wrapped by `<strong>` tags.

Note, however, it will not match if you provide a search string of "Google Books" (note the 's'). This is very basic, there is no stemming to account for variations of words / plurals etc nor does it check for word boundaries (ie you could search for 'oogl' and it will match G**oogl**e). Depending on your requirements, this might be sufficient though.

Comment: yes, it s correct one, but i need to display only 150 characters. so then how to change this coding.. explain me....

Comment: after that use like this,

$outputstring = substr($outputString,0,150);

Comment: suppose my total string is 5000 characters, i searched string is where i dont know the position. in this time hw can i get correct position... thats  i asked can i get particular 150 characher from string and also contain my searched word...

Comment: The string have more characters...

the searched word in the starting or ending or mid position...

we dont know the location...

so how can i get the word correctly...

sorry i lack of communication...

so thats y i cant explain correctlyy...

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with strtr, it can be faster on large chunks of text.

```
$text = strtr($text, array("search term" => "<b>search term</b>"));
```

Be careful to use the array as parameter, as this function behavior is slightly different using string parameters